# Setting the shortcut keys for brightness in Ubuntu 16.04 i3wm

Tags: ubuntu

I have set i3wm in Ubuntu. I am not able to set working shortcuts for increasing/decreasing screen brightness even though all other shortcuts are working. 
I tried

```
bindsym $mod+114 exec xbacklight +10
bindsym $mod+113 exec xbacklight -10
```

However found out that xbacklight does not work with Radeon. My brightness file is located here : **/sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl0/brightness**.

Only able to change the brightness by running the command 
**echo n > /sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl0/brightness**.

How can I set working shortcut keys for brightness control?

Answer (score 2):

You have to do the following two steps:

1. Use bindcodes instead of bindsym when using keycodes

   ```
   bindcode 233 exec "xbacklight +5"
   bindcode 232 exec "xbacklight -5"
   ```
2. Add an entry for your device in **/usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d/**: Create a file called **20-radeon.conf** or similar. In this file you add an entry that looks like this:

   ```
   Section "Device"
      Identifier  "card0"
      Driver      "intel"
      Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
      BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
   EndSection
   ```

Replace the intel vendor with your own (supposedly radeon and radeon_backlight, but that's only a guess!).

Hope this works or at least helps. Good luck!